# Install SCIP on Eclipse

Tags: scip

I am trying to make the SCIP work with Java/Windows 7. I have installed Eclipse Mars.

I am kind of new to the SCIP. I read through the installation procedure and try to install the SCIP. But I can't understand the installation procedure clearly. I downloaded [this](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipjni-3.2.1.win.x86_64.msvc.opt.spx.zip) library, and installed the .jar and the .dll like I am used to do, however there are very few examples online about SCIP in Java, and I can't import this correctly. 
Can anyone tell me how to install the SCIP or guide me to an example?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with the file names in the JNI library. I fixed this issue and updated the library [here](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipjni-3.2.1.win.x86_64.msvc.opt.spx.zip). Please note that you need to have a 64bit version of Java to run the SCIP-JNI.

Do the following steps to run the JniKnapsack example which you can find in

```
 <scipdir>/interfaces/jni/examples/JniKnapsack/java/JniKnapsack.java
```

1. copy the JniKnapsack.java into a new Java project
2. add the scip.jar as an external JAR (**Properties** > **Java Build Path** > **Add External Jars**)
3. put the libjscip*.{dll,lib} and libscip-3.2.1*.{dll,lib} next to the scip.jar or inside the main directory of your new project
4. replace the line `JniScipLibraryLoader.loadLibrary();` in JniKnapsack.java with `System.loadLibrary("libjscip-0.1.mingw.x86_64.msvc.opt.spx");`

Now you should be able to run the program as an **Java Application**.