# SCIP JNI - JNIKnapsack example fails to run

Tags: scip

I'm trying to use SCIP JNI using the SCIP Optimization Suite and compiling it from the source code using Ubuntu 16.04.
I compiled the jni interface folder, using the instructions provided in the site, but there seems to be an issue with the JniKnapsack example. When running it using the Makefile and the run.sh available in the folder:

```
make run
```

The output is:

```
SCIP version 3.2.1 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode: optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 2.2.1] [GitHash: c7c6c02]
Copyright (c) 2002-2016 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik Berlin (ZIB)
created variables <x0>
variables pointer <1958512920>
created variables <x1>
variables pointer <1958513276>
created variables <x2>
variables pointer <1958517056>
created variables <x3>
variables pointer <1958517412>
created variables <x4>
variables pointer <1958517768>
created variables <x5>
variables pointer <1958518124>
created variables <x6>
variables pointer <1958521568>
created variables <x7>
variables pointer <1958521924>
created variables <x8>
variables pointer <1958522280>
created variables <x9>
variables pointer <1958522636>
*** 10.0
*** 11.0
*** 12.0
*** 13.0
*** 14.0
*** 15.0
*** 16.0
*** 17.0
*** 18.0
*** 19.0
*** 11
*** Value found: -1.0
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x74823c65, pid=18485, tid=3057216320
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libscip.linux.x86.gnu.opt.so+0x44bc65]  SCIPsolGetVal+0x35
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/david/workspace/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/scip-3.2.1/interfaces/jni/examples/JniKnapsack/hs_err_pid18485.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Do you use a 32bit version of Java? The output suggests that you are using  a 64bit variant of Java but a 32bit version of SCIP. You should either switch to 64bit SCIP or 32bit Java. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: I'm using 32-bit kernel and 32 bit java -- uname -i outputs:i686; java -version: openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Per indication on a response you provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001271/install-scip-on-eclipse/37007473#37007473 I successfully compiled and ran the same example in an x64 linux distro. Knowing that on the SCIP site there is a x86 version available my guess would be that some issue must exist with the source code of the SCIPSuite.